# Get name of input react

Tags: html, reactjs

Newbie to react. I would like to find out how to get the name of a input inorder to place in a method parameter.

```
          <div >
                <FormGroup style={{ width: "400px" }}>
                  <h3>Enter Barcode</h3>

                  <InputGroup className="mb-4">
                    <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
                      <InputGroupText>
                        Barcode:
                      </InputGroupText>
                    </InputGroupAddon>
                    <Input type="text" name="**BarcodeNUmber**" onChange={(e) => { this.onChangeInput(e) }} />
                  </InputGroup>

                </FormGroup>
                <Button onClick={() =>this.onProductSearch(**BarcodeNUmber**)} color="primary" type="button">
                  <span className="btn-inner--text">Confirm</span>
                </Button>
              </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually do not use class components with react but here we go.
Changes:

1. Button is within FormGroup
2. onSubmit added to FormGroup
3. Button type to "submit"
4. using value of input instead of name.
5. state controls input value

App.js

```
import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { barcodeNumber: null };

  onProductSearch(barcodeNumber) {
    ///do what you want
  }

  onSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.onProductSearch(this.state.barcodeNumber);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <FormGroup onSubmit={this.onSubmit} style={{ width: "400px" }}>
          <h3>Enter Barcode</h3>

          <InputGroup className="mb-4">
            <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
              <InputGroupText>Barcode:</InputGroupText>
            </InputGroupAddon>
            <Input
              type="text"
              value={this.state.barcodeNumber}
              onChange={(e) => {
                this.setState({barcodeNumber: e.target.value);
              }}
            />
          </InputGroup>
          <Button color="primary" type="submit">
            <span className="btn-inner--text">Confirm</span>
          </Button>
        </FormGroup>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: make sure your FormGroup can properly handle the onSubmit prop, too

Answer (score 0):

Access it from the `event` object:

```
onChangeInput(e) {
    console.log(e.target.name);
}
```

Comment: You could also create ref to get name of input

Comment: OK i am getting a error that states {e is not defined}. I am Probably doing somthing wrong.  Basically I want to use the **BarcodeNUmber** in the button to call a method and use the actual input object to send to the method/function.

Comment: Is there a reason you are assigning barcodeNumber to the name? What gets typed in the input? the barcodeNumber?

Comment: Yes the barcode gets typed into the input box. Then in the method/function, i unwrap it like you showed me. (ie e.target.value)

Comment: I submitted new answer so I could show new code

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that handles the `onChange` and extract the value from the event target.

```
export default function App() {

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.name, ":", e.target.value);
  }

  return (
    <div >
      <FormGroup style={{ width: "400px" }}>
        <h3>Enter Barcode</h3>
        <InputGroup className="mb-4">
          <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
            <InputGroupText>
              Barcode:
            </InputGroupText>
          </InputGroupAddon>
          <Input type="text" name="**BarcodeNUmber**" onChange={handleChange} />
        </InputGroup>
      </FormGroup>
      <Button onClick={() =>this.onProductSearch(**BarcodeNUmber**)} color="primary" type="button">
        <span className="btn-inner--text">Confirm</span>
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```